LangChain: Ensuring LLM Only Uses Explicitly Stated Information in Mental Health Assessment Tool
I'm developing a mental health assessment tool using LangChain and OpenAI. The goal is to analyze user inputs and answer predefined questions about their mental state based solely on the information explicitly stated in their input.
Current Implementation
My current implementation uses a ChatPromptTemplate with system and human messages, followed by a ChatOpenAI model and JsonOutputParser. However, I'm getting mixed results. The model sometimes infers information not explicitly stated in the input.
Here's a simplified version of my questions.json (there are around 30 questions in total):
[
  {
    "name": "Age",
    "question_text": "Select your age group:",
    "displayOptions": [
      "12 to 21",
      "21 to 30",
      "30 to 50", 
      "60 and above"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Gender",
    "question_text": "Select your gender:",
    "displayOptions": [
      "Male",
      "Female",
      "Others"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "StressRecently", 
    "question_text": "Have you been stressed about something recently?",
    "displayOptions": [
      "Yes",
      "No"
    ]
  }
]

Sample user input:

I'm 32 year old guy. I've been working 10-12 hours in office although I am working from home. I've trouble sleeping.

Response I'm getting:
{
  "analysis": {
    "AbnormalDailyActivity": "Unknown",
    "AbnormalDisinterested": "Unknown",
    "AbnormalDistraction": "Unknown",
    "AbnormalEating": "Unknown",
    "AbnormalMindMaking": "Unknown",
    "AbnormalWeightGain": "Unknown",
    "Age": "30 to 50",
    "ChronicHealth": "Unknown",
    "CurrentChallenges": "Unknown",
    "CurrentSituation": "Unknown",
    "Employment": "Unknown",
    "EnergyLevel": "Yes",
    "EngageActivities": "Unknown",
    "EnjoyNormalDay": "Unknown",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "GoodHealth": "Unknown",
    "ServiceType": "Unknown",
    "Staylocation": "Home or at relatives",
    "StressAge": "Unknown",
    "StressLoss": "Unknown",
    "StressRecently": "Yes",
    "StressShared1": "Unknown",
    "WellBeingHealth": "Unknown",
    "WellBeingNormal": "Unknown",
    "WellBeingSatisfy": "Unknown",
    "WorklifeBalance": "Unknown",
    "Workstress": "Unknown",
    "lackofMotivation": "Yes"
  },
  "response_time": "3.45 seconds"
}

Issue
The model is inferring data not explicitly stated in the user's input. For example, it's answering "Yes" to StressRecently, even though the user didn't mention stress.
Current Prompt
Here's the code I'm using for my prompting:
system_template = '''You are a highly precise mental health assessment assistant. Your role is to analyze user inputs and respond to a set of predefined questions about their mental state and well-being. Follow these strict guidelines:

1. Only use information explicitly stated in the user's input.
2. DO NOT make inferences, assumptions, or guesses about unstated information.
3. Respond with "Unknown" for any question that cannot be directly answered from the given information.
4. Be extremely cautious: it's better to answer "Unknown" than to potentially provide incorrect information.
5. Focus solely on the content of the user's statement, not on interpreting or diagnosing their condition.
6. DO NOT interpret or diagnose. Only report what is directly stated.

Remember, this is a critical assessment tool dealing with real patients' mental health. Accuracy and caution are paramount.
'''

human_template = '''Carefully read the following user input:

User's statement: {text}

Based solely on this input, provide answers to the following questions. Use "Unknown" for any question that cannot be answered with absolute certainty based on the explicit content of the user's statement.

Questions:
{questions}

While answering the questions, use the question_text field to answer the question. Don't rely on just the name field.
Provide your answers in JSON format. Include all questions, using "Unknown" for any that cannot be confidently answered based solely on the given information.'''

prompt_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
    ("system", system_template),
    ("human", human_template)
])

chain = prompt_template | model | parser

def analyze_situation(text):
    start_time = time.time()
    
    result = chain.invoke({
        "questions": json.dumps(questions_json, indent=2),
        "text": text
    })
    
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    
    return result, elapsed_time


How can I improve my prompt to ensure the model only uses explicitly stated information?
Are there better LangChain components or techniques I should consider for this task?
As a LangChain novice, what best practices should I follow for this kind of application?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This question is essentially about prompt engineering, which is off-topic for StackOverflow. Consider the GenAI StackExchange site instead.

I was hoping to get a direction so that i can know if this is specific to the prompt engineering or there are any specific langchain components which could help me solve the issue.
